# Downloading github archived repositories

Tags: git, github, conda

I downloaded `wget -c https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/FALCON_unzip/archive/funzip_052016.tar.gz`, but the FALCON folder is empty. How is it possible to download archived which contained link repositories?

Thank you in advance.

Mic

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `FALCON_unzip-funzip_052016/` folder instead.  That is what is used inside the zip file.

Comment: Unfortunately, `FALCON_unzip-funzip_052016/FALCON/` is empty.

Comment: Use another unzip-program.